# Running CDK deploy in a CI environment

Tags: aws-cdk

Going through [this tutorial](https://cdkworkshop.com/).

When running `cdk deploy` it asks for permission to deploy. I'm assuming this is because of the IAM resources created earlier in the tutorial. I can't run this in a CI environment as there would be no way to answer that question. It looks like there is no way to run it in a non-interactive way?

I also couldn't find anything in the documentation?

Answer (score 13):

If there are changes to existing IAM roles/users etc or new ones are created you have to confirm the deploy by typing "y" you can bypass this with the option `--require-approval=never`